# How to run a Flask command from Python code and capture output?

Tags: python, flask, command

I have a bunch of [custom commands](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#custom-commands) in a Flask project. Those can be run from shell, e.g.

```
$ flask create-user admin
```

I also need to run the commands (and capture any output) directly from Python code. How can I do that? I would like to avoid spawning subprocesses, if possible.

Comment: did you try to import code and run `create_user("admin")` ?

Comment: @furas: This kind of works. However, 1) I get the command as user input, so I need to resolve it to the function somehow 2) I need to capture the output (stdout and stderr) from the function.

Comment: I don't know what you try to do but you can use `input()` or `sys.argv` to get input from command line and use `if/else` to run code ie. `if sys.argv[1] == "create_user": create_user(...)`. You can keep it also in dict `cmd = { "create_user":  create_user, ...}` and do `cmd[sys.argv[1]]("admin")`. Eventually you can try to use `getattr(..., sys.argv[1])("admin")` to access function using string name.

Comment: normally you can run `flask create-user admin > output.txt` to redirect `stdout` to file and get output. In Python you can assign file to `sys.stdout` to catch all output. Eventually you can assign `io.StringIO()` to catch it to memory. Or you can assing own class which have `.write()` and `.seek()`. And in `.write()` you can catch output to variable in memory.